# Spring Cloud Stream with Rabbit Binder - source/sink queue names don't match

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-stream

Recently, I started to play with Spring Cloud Stream and RabbitMQ binder.

If I understood everything correctly when two services want to pass message, one should configure *source* for sending messages and other should configure *sink* for receiving messages - both should use the same *channel*.

I have *channel* named `testchannel`. I noticed, though, that *source* created RabbitMQ binding:

- exchange `testchannel`,
- routing key `testchannel`,
- queue `testchannel.default` (durable),

while *sink* created RabbitMQ binding:

- exchange `testchannel`,
- routing key `#`,
- queue `testchannel.anonymous.RANDOM_ID` (excusive).

I skipped prefix, for brevity.

Now when I ran both applications. First one sends message to `testchannel` exchange, which then is routed to both queues (I assume routing key is `testchannel`). Second application consumes message from random queue, but message from default queue is never consumed.

My other problem is - 2nd app is using only *sink*, but it also creates binding for output channel, which is `output` by default, because I haven't specified anything.

I build both apps with the same Gradle script:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

dependencies {
    compile(
            'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit',
    )
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}
```

First app properties:

```
server.port=8010
spring.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.default.prefix=z.
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input=start
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output=testchannel
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=host1:5672,host2:5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=user
spring.rabbitmq.password=psw
```

Fisrt app source code:

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
...
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
public byte[] handleIncomingMessage(byte[] payload) {}
```

Second app properties:

```
server.port=8011
spring.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.default.prefix=z.
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input=testchannel
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=host1:5672,host2:5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=user
spring.rabbitmq.password=psw
```

Second app source code:

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
...
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT)
public void handleIncomingMessage(byte[] payload) {}
```

So my questions are.

- Shouldn't *source* and *sink* use the same channel and as result the same broker queue? What is proper configuration to achieve that? (My goal is to have have multiple *sink* service instances, but only one should consume the message.)
- Should framework create output binding when I am using only *sink*? If yes, how to disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default; consumers each get their own queue; it's a publish/subscribe scenario.

There is a notion of a consumer `group` so you can have multiple instances compete for messages from the same queue.

When binding the producer, a default queue is bound.

If you wish to subscribe to the `default` group; you have to set the group:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=default
```

If you don't provide a group, you get an exclusive, auto-delete queue.

**EDIT**

Since the default queue is durable, you should also set

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.durableSubscription=true
```

to avoid a warning when the consumer binds and to make sure the queue is durable if the consumer binds first and the queue doesn't exist yet.

Comment: You said by default. Is there any configuration that would allow me to change it into peer to peer scenario? Direct channel seems to better suit my needs.

Comment: Setting the group to `default` does that.

Comment: I haven't changed 1st service (A). I change 2nd service's (B) input channel's group to `default`. When I run A, then B - B complains about queue durability. Exception: `channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable' for queue 'z.test.default' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true', class-id=50, method-id=10)`

Comment: Correction: Using group `default` settings, indeed, works as a peer to peer. Thank you. Above mentioned exception is a warning only. (Not sure there should be any warning, since this setting is one of the expected use case. But that is just a digression.) As for the sink-only use case resulting with output queue - probably fixed, as I do not see it now, and today's build downloaded new version of Spring libraries. Once again, thanks for help.

Comment: Ah one last question - is it possible to change output default group name? The same property for output channel does not seem to have effect. Output queue always ends with `.default`.

Comment: You can suppress the warning using `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.durableSubscription=true` - the default queue created by the producer is always durable. I have started a discussion internally about the default queue created by the source and have opened an [issue here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/317).

Comment: if we have 5 partitions and if we have just two instances in CF for same destination, will it process? I mean can one consumer process multiple paritions - how this will work or how we need to configure such..

Comment: You should ask a new question; the admins don't like extended commentary on questions/answers. No, with rabbit and partitioned consumers, you need an instance for each partition - the `spring.cloud.stream.instance-index` property indicates the partition. There are other ways (aside from partitioning) to achieve what you want though; too much to explain here; ask a new question and I'll answer tomorrow.